# Jquery - How to remove link or unwrap children element if link attribute href contain string that i need to find?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried my Jquery but it doesn't remove or unwrap anything that i want. Can you please look at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong. Thank you very much.

Jquery:

```
$('.link3').each(function(){
      if($('.link3').attr('href').indexOf('139_case-study-distributing-data-from-remote-plants.html') != -1){  
         if($(this).children().lenght > 0){
            $(this).children.unwrap();
         }else{
            $(this).remove();
         }
      }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-2">

    <a class="link3 ui-link" href="/cz/cs/24_produkty-a-partneri/139_case-study-distributing-data-from-remote-plants.html?do=article"> </a>
    <div class="mod-subcats ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-inset ui-collapsible-collapsed" data-theme="d" data-role="collapsible">
    <div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-collapsible-content-collapsed" aria-hidden="true">
      <a class="link3 ui-link" href="/cz/cs/24_produkty-a-partneri/139_case-study-distributing-data-from-remote-plants.html?do=article">
       <h2> ... </h2>
      </a>
      <ul id="mod-links" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow" data inset="true" data-theme="d" data-role="listview">
        ..content
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br class="clear">

</div>
```

Comment: Rewrite to children(). Not removing or unwrapping.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing parentheses and misspelling to length:

```
$('.link3').each(function(){
      if($('.link3').attr('href').indexOf('139_case-study-distributing-data-from-remote-plants.html') != -1){  
         if($(this).children().lenght > 0){ //should be length
            $(this).children.unwrap(); //here should be children()
         }else{
            $(this).remove();
         }
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> length spelling is wrong. use length and missing parenthesis in your code

```
  //if($(this).children().lenght > 0){
```

Comment: I did what U write but without result ? Did I miss something in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

change to

```
$('.link3').each(function(){
      if($('.link3').attr('href').indexOf('139_case-study-distributing-data-from-remote-plants.html') != -1){  
         if($(this).children().length > 0){
            $(this).children.unwrap(); //here should be children()
         }else{
            $(this).remove();
         }
      }
});
```

Comment: rewrite to children(). Tried without result.

Answer (score 0):

You can get there with css:

```
  $('.link3[href*="139_case-study-distributing-data-from-remote-plants.html"] > *').unwrap();
  $('.link3:not([href*="139_case-study-distributing-data-from-remote-plants.html"])').remove();
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for post can you put comments to your code. BTW I have to remove link with that string or unwrap children if link's got children element ?

Comment: Yes, it's just CSS. You can [read about it here](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/)